# how to add method called on input into arraylist?

Tags: arraylist

```
public void oneFrame(String dnaInput) {
    ArrayList<String> oneFrame = new ArrayList<>();

    int index = 0;
    while (index < dnaInput.length()){
        index += 3;

        if (dnaInput.contains("ATG")){
            restOfORF(dnaInput);
            break;
        }

    }
```

How can I add this method called on input, "restOfORF(dnaInput)" into an 'oneFrame' arraylist and then return it? thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `restOfORF` returns a `String`, you can call `oneFrame.add` and pass it as an argument. You should also change the method's signature and return it from the method:

```java
public List<String> oneFrame(String dnaInput) {
    List<String> oneFrame = new ArrayList<>();

    int index = 0;
    while (index < dnaInput.length()){
        index += 3;

        if (dnaInput.contains("ATG")){
            oneFrame.add(restOfORF(dnaInput));
            break;
        }
    }
    return oneFrame;
}
```